# How to run a python script with another virtual environment dependencies in a DAG in Airflow?

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv, airflow

**How to run a python script with another virtual environment dependencies in a DAG in Airflow? Not using the main python environment where airflow is installed.**

I have a docker container running the puckel image and I'm trying to create a DAG which consists of a blob sensor and a bash operator. The bash operator is meant to run a python script, which has dependencies of specific packages different than the main python installation where Airflow is installed.

The way I'm doing it is by building a (python 3.7) virtual env in the image and place it in "~/new_env/" with a version of azure-storage-blob=12.1.0. In the BashOperator I have the following definition:

```
BashOperator(
        task_id='task_id_1',
        bash_command=f'{PATH_TO_VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/python {PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT_1}/some_py_script.py'
    )
```

The python environment where Airflow is running has azure-storage-blob=1.3.0.
The script gets stuck in running.

Is this not a good approach? if not, has anyone solved this issue or use case?

Thanks